# jboss 6.x runtime server shows blank page

Tags: java, jboss, eclipse

I am running my server `JBoss` 6.x runtime server with `eclipse Kepler`. When I run my server I get:

```
JBoss 6.x Runtime Server [Started,synchronized]
```

But when access `http://localhost:8080/` i got blank page.
i change some settings but nothing help.
i have `xampp` already installed on my windows os.

[image]

Here is my log file:

```
2015-07-05 00:26:31,296 ERROR [ProfileServiceBootstrap] (Thread-2) Failed to load profile:: org.jboss.deployers.client.spi.IncompleteDeploymentException: Summary of incomplete deployments (SEE PREVIOUS ERRORS FOR DETAILS):

DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "jboss.web.deployment:war=/juddi" is in error due to the following reason(s): java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 16: file:/C:/Program Files/jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/all/deploy/juddi-service.sar/juddi.war/
  Deployment "jboss.web.deployment:war=/invoker" is in error due to the following reason(s): java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 16: file:/C:/Program Files/jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/all/deploy/httpha-invoker.sar/invoker.war/
  Deployment "vfs:///C:/Program%20Files/jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/all/deploy/ROOT.war" is in error due to the following reason(s): java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 16: file:/C:/Program Files/jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/all/deploy/ROOT.war/

    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.checkComplete(DeployersImpl.java:1228) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.checkComplete(MainDeployerImpl.java:905) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.checkComplete(MainDeployerPlugin.java:87) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.ProfileDeployerPluginRegistry.checkAllComplete(ProfileDeployerPluginRegistry.java:107) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:135) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:56) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer.startBootstraps(AbstractServer.java:827) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-6]
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer$StartServerTask.run(AbstractServer.java:417) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-6]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_40]

2015-07-05 00:26:31,358 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (Thread-2) Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-localhost%2F127.0.0.1-8080
2015-07-05 00:26:31,358 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol] (Thread-2) Starting Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-localhost%2F127.0.0.1-8009
2015-07-05 00:26:31,358 INFO  [org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer] (Thread-2) JBossAS [6.1.0.Final "Neo"] Started in 57s:243ms
2015-07-05 00:26:37,875 INFO  [org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment] (RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1) deploy, ctxPath=/helloworldStruts2
2015-07-05 00:26:38,260 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1) Context [/helloworldStruts2] startup failed due to previous errors: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Filter mapping specifies an unknown filter name struts2
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.validateFilterMap(StandardContext.java:2017) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addFilterMap(StandardContext.java:1973) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.JBossContextConfig.processWebMetaData(JBossContextConfig.java:328) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.JBossContextConfig.applicationWebConfig(JBossContextConfig.java:211) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.start(ContextConfig.java:417) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:182) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.JBossContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(JBossContextConfig.java:206) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:115) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3773) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:294) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy(TomcatDeployment.java:146) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeployment.java:476) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:118) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:95) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [:1.8.0_40]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_40]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_40]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_40]
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:271) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:670) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:206) [:2.2.0.SP2]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy43.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:53) [:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:41) [:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceControllerContext.install(ServiceControllerContext.java:301) [:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:671) [:6.1.0.Final (Build SVNTag:JBoss_6.1.0.Final date: 20110816)]
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:443) [:6.1.0.Final (Build SVNTag:JBoss_6.1.0.Final date: 20110816)]
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.start(ServiceDeployer.java:189) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:102) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:49) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:63) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:55) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1832) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1550) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1571) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1491) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.change(DeployersImpl.java:1983) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:1076) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:679) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.process(MainDeployerPlugin.java:106) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileControllerContext$DelegateDeployer.process(ProfileControllerContext.java:143) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.deploy(ProfileDeployAction.java:151) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.installActionInternal(ProfileDeployAction.java:94) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:54) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:42) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper$BasicProfileActivation.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:190) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:87) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activateProfile(ProfileActivationService.java:215) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activate(ProfileActivationService.java:159) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.AbstractProfileService.activateProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:154) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.system.tools.ProfileServiceToolsFacade.addURI(ProfileServiceToolsFacade.java:233) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.system.tools.LegacyDeploymentScannerAdapter.addURL(LegacyDeploymentScannerAdapter.java:140) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.system.tools.DeploymentScanner.addURL(DeploymentScanner.java:91) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.system.tools.DeploymentScanner.addURL(DeploymentScanner.java:83) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [:1.8.0_40]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_40]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_40]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_40]
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:271) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:670) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.system.server.jmx.MBeanServerWrapper.invoke(MBeanServerWrapper.java:138) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_40]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_40]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_40]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_40]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_40]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [:1.8.0_40]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_40]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_40]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_40]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_40]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_40]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_40]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [:1.8.0_40]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_40]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_40]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_40]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$254(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_40]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$$Lambda$2/2055022979.run(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_40]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [:1.8.0_40]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_40]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_40]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_40]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_40]
```

Server port selected 8080, but still something is missing. Please anybody help me.

Comment: Probably your web.xml is buggy, there is no struts2 filter defined in it.

Comment: It looks the [community](http://serverfault.com/users/8897/sven) thinks your question is off-topic here. I suggest to reask this on http://unix.stackexchange.com, where it would have probably a much better chance to survive.